# Is there a collection backed ResultSet implementation in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm going to test a class that interacts with a ResultSet, but I don't want to actually hit database to do it, I want a ResultSet implementation that accepts a type argument and use a List as its backup data to return data. It doesn't need to have all the bells and whistles of a real result set. Only need to have `next()`, `getObject(int/String)` implemented. Is there such a thing that already exists?

Comment: I don't know of any such implementation. You either need to write it yourself, or mock it.

Comment: That's exactly what I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created one myself, please refer to [ListBackedResultSet](https://gist.github.com/imgen/5243577)

Answer (score 1):

Within the Java library, there is `javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet` with associated implementation. It subtypes `ResultSet`. (I haven't read the documentation.)

Comment: Probably not what I wanted. It still involves database stuff heavily.

Comment: You can subclass CachedRowSet without need to implement all interface members.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Spring's JdbcTemplate:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> queryForList(String sql);
```

The results is a List (one entry for each row) of Maps (one entry for each column using the column name as the key).